# Swift3/Firebase Update child

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

// Problem solved
i found it out by myself, still thanks for your help :=)

I try to build a Instagram like app for learning purposes.
I can upload and retrieve the data from Firebase.
When I upload a new picture, I set the value of comments to 0. 
So when a user comments, I want to update the value of the child ("kommentAnzahl") +1 for a new comment and minus -1 for a deleted one( the deleting is not important yet). So that I can let my label anzahlKommentare display the amount of  comments by users underneath each post ( just like Instagram does)

my complete code is down below

```
class MemesTableViewController: UITableViewController {

var kommentarArray = [FotoComment]()
var dataBaseRef : FIRDatabaseReference!
var storageRef : FIRStorageReference!
var posts = [PostMitBild]()
var segmentedControl : HMSegmentedControl!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

segmentedControl = HMSegmentedControl(sectionTitles: ["Top Heute", "Beliebteste", "Neue"])
  segmentedControl.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 300, height: 60)
    segmentedControl.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    segmentedControl.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white]
    segmentedControl.borderColor = UIColor.brown
    segmentedControl.tintColor = UIColor.black
    segmentedControl.selectionIndicatorColor = UIColor.gray


    segmentedControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(getter: MemesTableViewController.segmentedControl), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
    tableView.tableHeaderView = segmentedControl

 segmentedAction()
}

func segmentedAction() {
    if segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {

        let postRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("MemesBilder")

        postRef.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
            var newPost = [PostMitBild]()
            for post in snapshot.children {

                let Post = PostMitBild(snapshot: post as! FIRDataSnapshot)
                newPost.insert(Post, at: 0)

            }

            self.posts = newPost
            DispatchQueue.main.async {

                self.tableView.reloadData()


            }

            }, withCancel: { (error) in
                print(error.localizedDescription)
        })

    }

}

//------------------------------------------

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    if FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser == nil {

        let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Login")
        self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "postCell", for: indexPath) as! PostTableViewCell

    if let seconds = posts[indexPath.row].postDate {
         let timestamp = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: seconds)

        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy  HH:mm"
        cell.uploadDatum.text = dateFormatter.string(from: timestamp as Date)

    }

        cell.kommentarZähler.text = String(posts[indexPath.row].kommentarAnzahl)
        cell.usernameTextField.text = posts[indexPath.row].username
        cell.postContent.text = posts[indexPath.row].content


        storageRef = FIRStorage.storage().reference(forURL: posts[indexPath.row].userImageUrlString)
        storageRef.data(withMaxSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024, completion: { (data, error) in
            if error == nil {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    if let data = data {
                        cell.UserImageView.image = UIImage (data: data)
                    }
                }

            }else {
                print(error?.localizedDescription)
            }
        })

        let storageRef2 = FIRStorage.storage().reference(forURL: posts[indexPath.row].PostImageUrlString)
        storageRef2.data(withMaxSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024, completion: { (data, error) in
            if error == nil {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    if let data = data {

                        cell.postImageView.image = UIImage (data: data)
                    }

                }
            }else {
                print(error?.localizedDescription)
            }
        })

        return cell

}

//done!!!! ------------------------------------------

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {
      tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)


        let ref = posts[indexPath.row].ref
        ref!.removeValue()

        posts.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)

    }
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    var numberOfRows = 0
    switch segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex {
    case 0 :  numberOfRows = posts.count

    case 1: numberOfRows = posts.count

    default: break


    }

    return numberOfRows
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 420.00
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
        if segue.identifier == "addComment" {
            let vc = segue.destination as! CommentTableViewController
            let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!

            vc.selectedPosts = posts[indexPath.row]
        }

    }
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "addComment", sender: self)
    }
    if segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "addComment", sender: self)
    }
    if segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 2 {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "addComment", sender: self)
    }
}

}



import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseDatabase
import FirebaseStorage

class CommentTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var komentarZähler: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var UserImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var usernameTextField: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var postImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var postContent: UITextView!

    var dataBaseRef : FIRDatabaseReference!
    var storageRef : FIRStorageReference!
    var commentsArray = [FotoComment]()
    var selectedPosts:PostMitBild!
    var DataBaseRef : FIRDatabaseReference! {
    return FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    configurePost()

    let commentRef = selectedPosts.ref!.child("Kommentare")

    commentRef.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        var newComments = [FotoComment]()
        for item in snapshot.children {
            let neuerKommentar = FotoComment(snapshot: item as! FIRDataSnapshot)
            newComments.insert(neuerKommentar, at: 0)

        }
        self.commentsArray = newComments
        self.tableView.reloadData()

        }, withCancel: { (error) in
            print(error.localizedDescription)
    })

    }
    @IBAction func addComment(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

    let alertView = UIAlertController(title: "Kommentar", message: "Füge einen Kommentar hinzu", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
    alertView.addTextField { (textfield) in
        textfield.placeholder = "Einen neuen Kommentar hinzufügen"

    }

    let sendCommentAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Kommentieren", style: .default) { (action) in
        let textfield = alertView.textFields!.first!

        let comment = FotoComment(content: textfield.text! , postId: self.selectedPosts.postId , username: (FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.displayName!) , userImageUrlString: String(describing: FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.photoURL!), postDate: (NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970))

        let commentRef = self.selectedPosts.ref!.child("Kommentare").childByAutoId()

        let myReference = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
      myReference.child("MemesBilder").child("kommentarAnzahl").setValue(["kommentarAnzahl": 1])

        commentRef.setValue(comment.toAnyObject())

        // commentRef.child("kommentarAnzahl").updateChildValues(["kommentarAnzahl" : 1])

    }

    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Abbrechen", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
    alertView.addAction(sendCommentAction)
    alertView.addAction(cancelAction)
    self.present(alertView, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

    // 2----------------------------------------------

    func configurePost() {

    usernameTextField.text = selectedPosts.username
    postContent.text = selectedPosts.content


    storageRef = FIRStorage.storage().reference(forURL: selectedPosts.userImageUrlString)
    storageRef.data(withMaxSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024, completion: { (data, error) in
        if error == nil {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if let data = data {
                    self.UserImageView.image = UIImage (data: data)
                }
            }

        }else {
            print(error?.localizedDescription)
        }
    })
    let storageRef2 = FIRStorage.storage().reference(forURL: selectedPosts.PostImageUrlString)
    storageRef2.data(withMaxSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024, completion: { (data, error) in
        if error == nil {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if let data = data {

                    self.postImageView.image = UIImage (data: data)
                }

            }
        }else {
            print(error?.localizedDescription)
        }
    })

    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
      komentarZähler.text = "Kommentare: \(commentsArray.count)"

    return commentsArray.count

    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "commentCell", for: indexPath) as! CommentTableViewCell

    if let seconds = commentsArray[indexPath.row].postDate {
        let timestamp = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: seconds)

        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy  HH:mm:ss"
        cell.uploadDatum.text = dateFormatter.string(from: timestamp as Date)

    }

    cell.usernameTextField.text = commentsArray[indexPath.row].username
    cell.postContent.text = commentsArray[indexPath.row].content

    storageRef = FIRStorage.storage().reference(forURL: commentsArray[indexPath.row].userImageUrlString!)
    storageRef.data(withMaxSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024, completion: { (data, error) in
        if error == nil {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if let data = data {
                    cell.UserImageView.image = UIImage (data: data)
                }
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }


        }else {
            print(error?.localizedDescription)
        }

    })
  return cell
}

}

import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseStorage
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseDatabase

class AddImageViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIPickerViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var postImage: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!

    var dataBaseRef : FIRDatabaseReference! {
    return FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    }

    var storageRef : FIRStorageReference! {
    return FIRStorage.storage().reference()
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    @IBAction func chooseImage(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let pickerController = UIImagePickerController()
    pickerController.delegate = self
    pickerController.allowsEditing = true

    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Bild aussuchen", message: "Suche dir dein neues Profilbild aus", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

    let cameraAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Kamera", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
        pickerController.sourceType = .camera
        self.present(pickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    })
    let photoLibraryAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Fotoalbum", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
        pickerController.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        self.present(pickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    })
    let safedPhotoAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Fotos", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
        pickerController.sourceType = .savedPhotosAlbum
        self.present(pickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    })

    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Abbrechen", style: .destructive, handler: nil)
    alertController.addAction(cameraAction)
    alertController.addAction(photoLibraryAction)
    alertController.addAction(safedPhotoAction)
    alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

    present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
    self.postImage.image = image

    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    @IBAction func SafeAction(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    let data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.postImage.image!, 0.5)
    let metadata = FIRStorageMetadata()
    metadata.contentType = "image/jpeg"
    let postId = "\(FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.uid)\(NSUUID().uuidString)"
    let imagePath = "postIMAGES\(postId)/postPic.jpg"

    storageRef.child(imagePath).put(data!, metadata: metadata) { (metadata, error) in
        if error == nil {

            let postRef = self.dataBaseRef.child("MemesBilder").childByAutoId()
            let post = PostMitBild(content: self.textView.text!, postId: postId, username: (FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.displayName!)!, PostImageUrlString: String(describing: metadata!.downloadURL()!), userImageUrlString: String(describing: FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.photoURL!), postDate: (NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970), kommentarAnzahl: 0)

                postRef.setValue(post.toAnyObject())


            let vc =  UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Memes")
            self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)


        }else {
            print(error!.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
       _ = navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
    }

}
```

these are my 3 VC for the display of the pictures (MemesTableView), for adding pictures (AddImageView) and for comment the uploaded Picture ( CommentTableView)

down below how my Firebase Structure looks like

this is what my struct looks like
[image: this is what my struct looks like]

I want to update the number of votes in the func "addComment" by the value of 1 each time a user comments

[This is my JSON Tree in written format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3pU9.png)

Comment: You've included a photo of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export button in your Firebase Database console. Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: https://witzeapp-4ec48.firebaseio.com/     is that what you meant? :O sorry i am an absolut beginner.

Comment: OKAy i nils have updated it with a picture of my JSON tree in written format. Hope that helps .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- I have given a sample function for updating the vote count value in firebase. Try the following

  ```
  func adddComment() {
    dataBaseRef.child("MemesBilder").child(userId).child("anzahlKommentare").runTransactionBlock({ (currentData: FIRMutableData) -> FIRTransactionResult in
      var voteCount = currentData.value as? Double
      if (voteCount == nil) {
          voteCount = 0
      }
      currentData.value = voteCount! + 1
      return FIRTransactionResult.successWithValue(currentData)
  }) 
  }
  ```

  - You can also find the completer https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write

Comment: okay thank you so far :) but for what do i have to exchange the part ".child(userID)" ?  And if try this it always creates a new Path and is not updating the existing one :/

Comment: i think i have to get the randomly assigned ID of the post somehow because i create all my post by childbyAutoId and they get the them like "-KXH03xSgZdIvcCOzbfS" . so the second child ".child(userID)" has to access the randomly assigned code ( the specific key of the post)  of the commented post and update the value of "kommentarAzahl" within this post, right?

Comment: Yes, you are right and you need to perform that way as you mentioned in second comment.

Comment: The thing is how do I get the specific assigned ID of the post I am commenting ? That's my biggest concern .

Comment: You have to get the reference of the image to which one has commented. Using that reference you can get his user id.

Comment: i tried it by inserting the ID of a uploaded picture as a child ( DataBaseRef.child("MemesBilder").child("KXH03xSgZdIvcCOzbfS").child("kommentarAnzahl").runTransactionBlock ... but it is still not updating but adding a new one every time i comment and then crashes

Comment: I just cannot find a solution to access this specific ID, its always creating a new one even though i put the exact ID in the child which makes no sense to me tbh.

Comment: well i could find the rest to solve the problem, still thanks because your part of updating the vote count was the key i needed! Marked it as the correct answer